# JToken serializing to string json.net

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have an object...

```
public class myEntity
    {
        public string Foo
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Bar
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public JToken Quux
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
}
```

The values that I'm sending them are:
`"ABC", "20090101100000"` and `{"QuuxId":1234,"QuuxName":"Sam"}` respectively

When I do:

```
var serializedString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

the `serializedString` value is coming as below:

```
{"Foo":"ABC","Bar":"20090101100000","Quux":"  {\"QuuxId\":1234,\"QuuxName\":\"Sam\"}"}
```

I want the value of Quux to remain a JToken and not become string as below:

```
{"Foo":"ABC","Bar":"20090101100000","Quux":{"QuuxId":1234,"QuuxName":"Sam"}}
```

Comment: Your `Quux` is apparently a json string... not a json object. If you want it as an object, you have to deserialize that first.

Comment: @JeffMercado When I look at the value of Quux in visual studio debugger it shows me {"QuuxId":1234,"QuuxName":"Sam"} , is this not an object, it does not have the double apostrophes before and after the curly braces

Comment: Sure, when you look at it in the variables windows, you will see the string representation of the value. The classes were designed to display it that way. Just because it looks that way, doesn't mean it is. If you want to know what type it is, you _must_ look at the `Type` property.

Comment: @Arnab I don't see any problem. This code works:  `var obj = new myEntity() { Foo = "ABC", Bar = "20090101100000", Quux = new JObject(new JProperty("QuuxId", 1234), new JProperty("QuuxName", "Sam")) };                   var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);` The final json: **{"Foo":"ABC","Bar":"20090101100000","Quux":{"QuuxId":1234,"QuuxName":"Sam"}}**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't serialize a `string`, you have to `Parse` it into a `JToken`

```
string quux_string = "{\"QuuxId\":1234,\"QuuxName\":\"Sam\"}";

var data = new myEntity()
{
    Foo = "ABC",
    Bar = "20090101100000",
    Quux = JToken.Parse(quux_string)
};
```

Comment: I'm developing the middle tier.. The jToken is coming from the front tier on which I have no control.. is it possible to convert a JToken type string  into JToken type object without knowing the internals of the object

Comment: @Arnab Updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think this example can explain what you are doing wrong

```
JToken j1 = "{\"QuuxId\":1234,\"QuuxName\":\"Sam\"}"; //this is an ordinary string
JToken j2 = JToken.FromObject(new { QuuxId = 1234, QuuxName = "Sam" });

var str1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(j1);
var str2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(j2);
```

str1 will be:    `"{\"QuuxId\":1234,\"QuuxName\":\"Sam\"}"`

str2 will be: `{"QuuxId":1234,"QuuxName":"Sam"}`

Comment: I'm developing the middle tier.. The jToken is coming from the front tier on which I have no control.. is it possible to convert a JToken type string (j1) into JToken type object(j2) without knowing the internals of the object

Comment: @Arnab If you are sure jtoken's content is a string and contains a json then you can use `JObject.Parse`. But It seems the jtoken passed to you is not correctly formed